# Binary search function with (log n) time complexity

Tags: python

For example,

```
print(binary_search(7, [1, 5, 10])) # 2 
print(binary_search(42, (-5, 1, 3, 5, 7, 10))) # 6
```

my code:

```
def binary_search(x, seq):
    if len(seq) == 0
    low = 0
    high = len(seq)
    mid = (low+high)//2
    if x == seq[mid]:
       return mid
    elif x < seq[mid]:
         return binary_search(x,seq[:mid])
    elif x > seq[mid]:
         return mid + 1 + binary_search(x,seq[mid+1:]
```

Comment: You are missing a `)` on your last line. Please fix the code in your post

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 5):

Not much, you're missing a colon and a return statement on the 2nd line and a closing paren on the last:

```
def binary_search(x, seq):
    if len(seq) == 0: return 0
    low = 0
    high = len(seq)
    mid = (low+high)//2
    if x == seq[mid]:
        return mid
    elif x < seq[mid]:
        return binary_search(x,seq[:mid])
    elif x > seq[mid]:
        return mid + 1 + binary_search(x,seq[mid+1:])

print(binary_search(7, [1, 5, 10]))  # 2
print(binary_search(42, (-5, 1, 3, 5, 7, 10)))  # 6
```

Worth noting that there is a stdlib module for this: [`bisect.bisect_left()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left)

> The return value is suitable for use as the first parameter to list.insert() assuming that a is already sorted.

The arguments are just in the opposite order:

```
import bisect
print(bisect.bisect_left([1, 5, 10], 7))  # 2
print(bisect.bisect_left((-5, 1, 3, 5, 7, 10), 42))  # 6
```